# Display resultset in custom jtable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

Here is my complete code...

When I run this and click button its showing `nullpointer exception` at resultset

```
package com.openbravo.pos.followup;

/**
 *
 * @author manideep
 */
    public class FollowUp extends javax.swing.JPanel implements JPanelView, BeanFactoryApp {
    private AppView m_App;
    protected DataLogicCustomers dlCustomers;
    //  CustomerInfo customer;
    private AppConfig conf;
    // private ListProvider lpr
    private DefaultTableModel modelx, model;
    protected DataLogicFollowUp dlFollowUp;
    /**
     * Creates new form FollowUp
     */
    public FollowUp() {
        initComponents();
        String[] args = {};
        conf = new AppConfig(args);
        conf.load();
        jLabel3.setText("");
    } 
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        m_jTicketId3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        m_jTicketId1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jcmdOK = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jcmdCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();

        jLabel1.setText("Enter Date");

        jTextField1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 19));

        jButton1.setText("Submit");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        jButton3.setText("Customer");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Product");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        m_jTicketId3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        m_jTicketId3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.darkShadow")), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 4, 1, 4)));
        m_jTicketId3.setOpaque(true);
        m_jTicketId3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(160, 25));
        m_jTicketId3.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        m_jTicketId1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        m_jTicketId1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.darkShadow")), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 4, 1, 4)));
        m_jTicketId1.setOpaque(true);
        m_jTicketId1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(160, 25));
        m_jTicketId1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 158, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(m_jTicketId1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(m_jTicketId3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton3)
                            .addComponent(m_jTicketId3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton4))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                                .addComponent(m_jTicketId1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(24, 24, 24))
        );

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Customer", "Phone No.", "Product", "Last sold Qty.", "Consumption", "last sale date", "Delivery Date", "Remark 1", "Remark 2", "Stock(Y/N)", "Invoice No."
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(0);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setResizable(false);

        jcmdOK.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/openbravo/images/button_ok.png"))); // NOI18N
        jcmdOK.setText("OK");
        jcmdOK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jcmdOKActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jcmdCancel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/openbravo/images/button_cancel.png"))); // NOI18N
        jcmdCancel.setText("Cancel");
        jcmdCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jcmdCancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jCheckBox1.setText("Select All");
        jCheckBox1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        jCheckBox1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        jCheckBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(353, 353, 353)
                .addComponent(jcmdOK)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jcmdCancel)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1408, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jCheckBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(74, 74, 74))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jCheckBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 406, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jcmdOK)
                    .addComponent(jcmdCancel))
                .addGap(31, 31, 31))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void getListSRLine(Element e){
        String customer= getAttrDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("customer").item(0),"identifier");
        String phone= getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("phone").item(0));
        String product=getAttrDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("product").item(0),"identifier");
        String lastsoldqty=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("lastsoldqty").item(0));
        String consumption=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("consumption").item(0));
        String lastsaledate=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("lastsaledate").item(0));
        String deliverydate=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("deliverydate").item(0));
        String remark1=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("remark1").item(0));
        String remark2=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("remark2").item(0));
        String stock=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("stock").item(0));
        String invoiceno=getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("invoiceno").item(0));
     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
     model.addRow(new Object[]{customer,phone,product,lastsoldqty,consumption,lastsaledate,deliverydate,remark1,remark2,stock,invoiceno});
     //sortColumn(model, 1, true);
     model.fireTableDataChanged();
     jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
     jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(200);

     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);

     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(100);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(100);

     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(100);

     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(100);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(100);

     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(100);
     jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(0);

    }

    private void executeSearch() {
        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                    + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openbravopos", "postgres",
                    "postgres");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
                int colCount;
                String [] headers;
                Statement stmt = null;
         //       rs=(ResultSet) dlFollowUp.getFollowUpList();
        //       getFollowUplist();
               ResultSet rs = null;
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id,customer,phone,product,lastsoldqty,consumption,lastsaledate,deliverydate,remark1,remark2,stock,invoiceno FROM followup");
                java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
                        for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++){
                            objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
                        }
                 model.addRow(objects);
                }
                jTable1.setModel(model);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FollowUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }



        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

    public static String getAttrDataFromElement(Element e,String attr){
        return e.getAttribute(attr);
    }
    public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
     Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
      CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
      return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
  }
    private void jcmdOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jcmdOKActionPerformed
      // jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();


        //dispose();

    }//GEN-LAST:event_jcmdOKActionPerformed



    private void jcmdCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jcmdCancelActionPerformed

        dispose();

    }//GEN-LAST:event_jcmdCancelActionPerformed

    private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jCheckBox1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jCheckBox1ActionPerformed
String field="";
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        jLabel3.setText("");
        executeSearch();
       //     entity = response.getafilter();

    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton3ActionPerformed
        JCustomerFinder finder = JCustomerFinder.getCustomerFinder(this, dlCustomers);
        finder.setVisible(true);
        CustomerInfo custsel=finder.getSelectedCustomer();
        m_jTicketId3.setText(custsel.printName());
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton3ActionPerformed

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed
      /*  // TODO add your handling code here:
        JProductFinder finder = JProductFinder.getProductFinder(this, dlSales, m_App.getInventoryLocation(),m_App);
        finder.setVisible(true);
        ProductAttrInfoExt prod = finder.getSelectedProduct();
        m_jTicketId1.setText(prod.getName());*/
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed

    private void dispose(){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        jLabel3.setText(null);
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jcmdCancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jcmdOK;
    private javax.swing.JLabel m_jTicketId1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel m_jTicketId3;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return "Follow Up";
    }

    @Override
    public void activate() throws BasicException {
        resetFollowUp();
    }

    public void resetFollowUp(){
        jTextField1.setText("");
        m_jTicketId3.setText("");
        m_jTicketId1.setText("");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean deactivate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AppView app) throws BeanFactoryException {

        jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(250);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(250);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(250);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(250);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(200);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(200);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(100);

        DefaultTableModel modelx =  (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        for(int j=0;j< modelx.getRowCount();j++){

        }
        m_App=app;
//        setWarehouse(m_App.getWarehouseSearchKey());
        dlCustomers = (DataLogicCustomers) m_App.getBean("com.openbravo.pos.customers.DataLogicCustomers");
       }
    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialise the `Statement` object....

```
Statement stmt = null; // Look ma, I'm null
//       rs=(ResultSet) dlFollowUp.getFollowUpList();
//       getFollowUplist();
ResultSet rs = null;
// Look ma, I'm still null
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id,customer,phone,product,lastsoldqty,consumption,lastsaledate,deliverydate,remark1,remark2,stock,invoiceno FROM followup");
```

You need to create the `stmt` before you can use...

```
stmt = connection.createStatement();
```

You may find reading through the [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) tutorials of benifit

**Problem #2**

You define `model` as instance variable at the start of your `FollowUp` class...

```
private DefaultTableModel modelx, model;
```

But you never initialise it to anything....

I would imagine, based on your code, you would need to initialise it in your `executeSearch` method...

```
// You will need to fill this out with appropriate values,
// the number of columns in you JTable should match the
// the number columns from your query...
Object[] columns = new Object[]{....};
model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
while(rs.next()){
    Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
    for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++){
        objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
    }
    model.addRow(objects);
}
```

Comment: its unable to let me use stmt.executeQuery without initialise the stmt= null;

Comment: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!
You made it, take control your database now!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.openbravo.pos.followup.FollowUp.executeSearch(FollowUp.java:440)
 at com.openbravo.pos.followup.FollowUp.jButton1ActionPerformed(FollowUp.java:633)
 at com.openbravo.pos.followup.FollowUp.access$000(FollowUp.java:55)
 at com.openbravo.pos.followup.FollowUp$1.actionPerformed(FollowUp.java:117)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)

Comment: variable con not found

Comment: created "connection con;" still same

Comment: its bereaking at line  "model.addRow(objects);"

Comment: is this correct? as u saw above.. i created defaulttablemodel- model and also created an object for it.. then used it model.addRow(objects);

Comment: I don't see any where you create a `DefaultTableModel`, I see that you have declared, but that doesn't create an instance...

Comment: so wot should i do there?

Comment: im unable to explain the correct problem.. can i get ur skype/teamviewer so that u can see it once? plz

Comment: Worked :) thnx for the help sir.. i was a bit dumb in getting it :) ur a pro :)