# How to bind data to JTable using java code

Tags: java, mysql, swing, data-binding, jtable

[image: sample table]

I want to bind some table tuples in mysql database to above table shown image. I use netbean to design this GUI and table property have some features to bind data to this table. but I want to manually code it. as an example in below sqlQuery return data, how to bind to jtable using manual code ?

```
 String sqlQuery ="SELECT packet_id, packet_capacity FROM packing LIMIT 0,20 DESC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayResultSetinTableJTable.htm) to understand how to retrieve data from your DB and create a TableModel. The just call `yourTable.setModel(theModelFromResultSet)`;

You can use Db query based sort. Just pass the sort column as `ORDER BY` part of the query.

Or you can use the answer [Display resultset in custom jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652153/display-resultset-in-custom-jtable)